# SQL подсчет кол-ва повторяющихся значений в колонке с обновлением счетчика

Tags: sql

Есть массив с датой, идентификатором человека и неким показателем

| dt | tab_num | ger_sess |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 |
| 29.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 |
| 30.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 |
| 31.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 |
| 01.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 |
| 02.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 |
| 03.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 |
| 04.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 |

Необходимо, чтобы sql-запрос считал кол-во повторяющихся значений в столбце ger_sess в разрезе одного идентификатора сотрудника, при этом ранжировать по дате от большей к меньшей

В итоге должно получиться следующее:

| dt | tab_num | ger_sess | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 1 |
| 29.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 2 |
| 30.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |
| 31.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 1 |
| 01.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 2 |
| 02.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 3 |
| 03.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |
| 04.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |

У меня получился скрипт ниже, но выводимый результат меня не устраивает:

```
Create table temp_table (
  dt date,
  tab_num text,
  ger_sess int
 );
 insert into temp_table values 
    ('2022-08-28', '00ZP-1234', 1),
    ('2022-08-29', '00ZP-1234', 1),
    ('2022-08-30', '00ZP-1234', 0),
    ('2022-08-31', '00ZP-1234', 1),
    ('2022-09-01', '00ZP-1234', 1),
    ('2022-09-02', '00ZP-1234', 1),
    ('2022-09-03', '00ZP-1234', 0),
    ('2022-09-03', '00ZP-1234', 0)
;

select 
    tab_num, 
    dt, 
    ger_sess, 
    case when ger_sess = 1 then rank () over (partition by tab_num, ger_sess order by dt) else 0 end
from temp_table
order by dt
```

| dt | tab_num | ger_sess | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 1 |
| 29.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 2 |
| 30.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |
| 31.08.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 3 |
| 01.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 4 |
| 02.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 1 | 5 |
| 03.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |
| 04.09.2022 | 00ZP-1234 | 0 | 0 |

Работаю в GreenPlum с ядром от PostgreSQL

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky, готово, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное не самый красивый вариант. В подзапросе, через SUM попытался разметить строки которые идут по порядку `CASE WHEN ger_sess = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`. Тут для значений `ger_sess = 1` значение sum не увеличивается, поэтому это будет одна группа значений до тех пор, пока не попадется `ger_sess = 0`. Затем использую получененное значение для определения PARTITION для rank() :

```
SELECT t.tab_num,
       t.dt,
       t.ger_sess,
       CASE
           WHEN t.ger_sess = 1 THEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.tab_num, t.order_sum, t.ger_sess ORDER BY dt)
           ELSE 0 END
FROM (SELECT tab_num,
             dt,
             ger_sess,
             SUM(CASE WHEN ger_sess = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY tab_num ORDER BY dt) AS order_sum
      FROM temp_table
      ORDER BY dt) t;
```

Comment: может "не самый красивый", зато решил проблему. Спасибо, надо получше мне познакомиться с оконными функциями

Comment: @Akina , можно сделать это решение более красивым? `SUM` предназначена не для сортировки, как использую в ответе, может есть что-то походящее? В sql не силен как хотелось бы.

Comment: @user_Dima отметьте этот вопрос решенным